# solving partial differential equation, why $x$ taken as $\sqrt{c_1^2-y^2}$ , not $-\sqrt{c_1^2-y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

If $u(x,y)$ is solution of partial differential equation $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=z$ with $z(x,0)=\sin \frac{\pi}{4}x$ then $u(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ is

(1) $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{\frac{x}{4}}$

(2) $\frac{\pi}{4}e^{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}$

(3)$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$

(4) $\frac{\pi}{4}e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}$

I know we can use the auxiliary equations $\frac{dx}{-y}=\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{dz}{z}$ to obtain the solutions, first solution I got as $x^2+y^2=c^{2}_1$ and for second solution it was solved as :

$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}\frac{dy}{x}&=\frac{dz}{z}\\\frac{dy}{\sqrt{c_1^2-y^2}}&=\frac{dz}{z}\end{aligned}\end{equation}$

So here they used $x=\sqrt{c_1^2-y^2}$, so my query is since $x^2+y^2=c_1^2$, then $x$ will equal to $x=\pm \sqrt{c_1^2-y^2}$, so why I used the positive value for $x$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, the auxiliary equations should be $$\frac{dx}{-y} = \frac{dy}{x}$$ as $$x dx = -y dy \implies x^{2} + y^{2} = c_{1}^{2} \quad \text{not } \quad \frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{-y}$$ This also means the characteristic equation you wrote $$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dz}{z}$$ is wrong. Second, use \partial to get a partial derivative $\partial$. Third, both the positive and negative branches should be kept simultaneously when computing the second characteristic.

Comment: I made the required changes. I understood how they got first solution $x^2+y^2=c_1^2$, my query is about second solution where they used $x^2+y^2=c_1^2$ to obtain $x=\sqrt{c_1^2-y^2}$...my question why they using positive value for $x$, or can I use $x$ as $-\sqrt{c_1^2-x^2}$

Comment: See my third point above.

Comment: but what does it mean...not getting what you mean by ''keeping simultaneously''....do u mean instead of using just positive part we need to use $x=\pm\sqrt{c_1^2-y^2}$..?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean.